# Move uitableview cell to the top with animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xcode5

Be simple, am a newbie!.

So I have a uitableview with contents in each cell that can be changed from a web service.

I need to show, visually, when something is change in any cell. So I want to move a particular cell to the top when the contents of that cell is change...with animation!

Is this possible?? and how can it be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rows cannot be moved programmatically.

However, you can simultaneously insert and delete a row to simulate a move.

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:rowToMove]
                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPathToMoveTo]
                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
// update your dataSource as well.
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Answer (score 7):

The selected answer might have been correct before, but since iOS 5, you can do the move like so:

```
[tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:indexPathOfRowToMove toIndexPath:indexPathOfTopRow];
```